# Split in script editor using google apps

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automatically split some data coming in my spreadsheet. I want to split it at two points. The first point being `@` and the second point being `x`. For example, let's say `blah blah blah @ NYC x ten` would be `blah blah blah/ nyc/ ten`. 3 different cells instead of 1.

How do I solve the problem?

```
 function getME() {
  var response =UrlFetchApp.fetch(url +"/getMe");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function getUpdates() {
  var response =UrlFetchApp.fetch(url +"/getUpdates");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function setWebhook() {
  var response =UrlFetchApp.fetch(url +"/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}


function doGet (e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Hello" +JSON.stringify(e));
}

function doPost(e) {
var contents= JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),"Telegram Bot Update",JSON.stringify(contents,null,4))
 var name = contents.message.from.first_name;
 var text = contents.message.text;

  var id = contents.message.from.id;
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).appendRow ([text]);
}

function splitIntoThree() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var sA=vA[i][0].toString().split(/[@x]/);
    if(sA.length==3) {
      vA[i].splice(0,1,sA[0],sA[1],sA[2]);
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(2,1,vA.length,3).setValues(vA);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var s="blah blah blah @ NYC x ten"
var a=s.split(/[@x]/);
```

**Doing it to a column:**

```
function splitIntoThree() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet178');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var sA=vA[i][0].toString().split(/[@x]/);
    if(sA.length==3) {
      vA[i].splice(0,1,sA[0],sA[1],sA[2]);
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(2,1,vA.length,3).setValues(vA);
}
```

Sheet Before:

[image]

Sheet After:

[image]

Comment: I want to do it for a column. The blah blah stuff is gonna be the format of the column. Should i change something in the code? Sorry if i was not clear

Comment: I need to know more about the spreadsheet structure? Perhaps you can just share a spreadsheet example with us?

Comment: Hi cooper. The spreadsheet is looking like that. https://imgur.com/a/0Y4V5Q7
I put in your code but still doesnt work :/ I left everything the same except of the spreadsheet name in which i put my ssId

Comment: I don't want an image of your spreadsheet.  I guess I don't really need it any longer as I already made my own example.  Most likely you will need to modify my code a little to get it to work with your spreadsheet.  If you can share a copy of your spreadsheet I'll take another look at it.

Comment: The spredsheet has some private info so i dont know if i can share. i put the data in exactly the same columns as u did but no dice..

Comment: Well, I've already tested it on my account and it works fine.  So I guess you'll have to figure out on your own.

Comment: Guess so.. Thank you very much for your help any way!

Comment: hi again. i got it to work, but when new data comes in it breaks down and says The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. . any ideas?

Comment: Again without your code or your spreadsheet it's hard to say much of anything.  But that sort of error message is common.

Comment: What is the meaning of dm?

Comment: personal message! it says it's too long for here. sorry, total noob in SO

Comment: Well it means what it say the number of columns in you data does not match the number of columns in your data so your have some sort of problem with your setValues() method.

Comment: cant seem to figure it out. is it ok if i send u the code in the link u have in your profile? cant post it here for some reason.

Comment: hey @Cooper sorry to bother you again. i posted the code in the original post. can u check it out?
There are two things happening. First the code split does not happen automatically(i have to run the function in order for it to be done) and secondly if i put lets say 100 rows and run the function it's done correctly. If after that i add another row and try to run function again i get an error. Please, if u can help that would be great

Comment: I don't see where splitIntoThree() is called.

Comment: Is this where data comes in `SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).appendRow ([text]);` and is Sheet1 the left most sheet?

Comment: Perhaps this is where it should be `var text = contents.message.text;
  var row=text.split(/[@x]/);
  var id = contents.message.from.id;//should this id be ssId
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).appendRow (row);`

Comment: yes sheet 1 is the left most sheet. Sheet 1 is the sheet where data comes in through telegram. from telegram to sheet 1.
so what should i do? just instert the var row? that didnt work.
again sorry for my noobiness